# Get type of an object by index number?

Tags: typescript

I have a usecase like:

```
type ExtractTypeFromIndex<I> = ???

type foo = { a:string; b:number }
type a = ExtractTypeFromIndex<0> // string
type b = ExtractTypeFromIndex<1> // number
```

Anyone knows how to implement the `ExtractTypeFromIndex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an index in object that is not an array.

The same type foo could be defined as `type foo = { b: number, a: string }` How would the ExtractTypeFromIndex be expected to behave?

If you'd like to access type of the nth element in a array type like

```
type SomeArray = [string, number];
```

You can do this like this

```
type SomeArray = [string, number];

// valid
const a: SomeArray[0] = 'string';
const b: SomeArray[1] = 4

// invalid
const c: SomeArray[1] = 'string';
const d: SomeArray[0] = 4
```

Link to TS Playground

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=26#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgQQE6oIYigXigbQGdhUBLAOwHMAaKcgVwQCMJUBdAbgCguB6XqADcMAG1IATLgGM45YlAwAuWIhTos+AAxtcUAOTEyVPdxlzgUJsvhI0mEPgCMOvABYe-KBWFjJZ+VLWqnYazroGJBSUJtKy8uJBtuoO2rquQA

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is object index like Object.entries() but not the tuple.

Comment: @yaquawa unfortunately that is not possible in TypeScript.  The order of properties in an object type is *unobservable* in TypeScript because it does not effect assignability.  The types `type Foo = { a: string, b: number }` and type `type Bar = { b: number, a: string }` *are the same type in TypeScript*.  And while you could [try to tease order info out of the compiler](https://tsplay.dev/m3A6qw), it is [fraught with peril and can lead to disaster](https://tsplay.dev/wOaAdm).  You will need to give up on this or tell the compiler what order you expect, such as with a tuple in this answer.